# problem install chatterbot used windows10

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, chatterbot

I need install chatterbot on windows 10 . I used vscode .
When I used `pip install chatterbot` I get this error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' 'c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\acons\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hbj5lk__\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'

---

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python38\python.exe' 'c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\acons\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hbj5lk__\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Please try to use `py -m pip install chatterbot`.

Comment: How are you trying to install it? Which commands did you type?

Comment: I used pip install chatterbot  .I tried your idea but is the same message

Comment: Is this in a virtual environment or are you using your global environment and pip to do the installation?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason: Chatterbot is indirectly using blis 0.2.4 And that version is not providing precompiled wheels for python 3.8 To fix that issue**

- Uninstall the current python version | To check the version type in cmd ***python --version***
- Download & Install python 3.7 https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0-amd64.exe
- Then install chatterbot ***pip install chatterbot***